# Why my numbers are rounded by themself

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have two tables : Product and Order. My projetc is an asp mvc3 project, and I work with Entity Framework.

In product, I have the field : Price (numeric 19,2)
In order, I have the field : UnitPrice (numeric 19,2)

This price should be the same, and they are except that in my Order table, my numbers are rounded.

Any idea for why ?

There are my Models class

```
public class Product
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int      ProductId   { get; set; }

        [StringLength(160)]
        public string   Name        { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Description")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string   Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="error")]
        [Range(0.00, 10000.00, ErrorMessage="Error")]
        public decimal   Price       { get; set; }

        public virtual List<OrderDetail> Order { get; set; }
    }


  public class Order
    {

        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: My magic crystal ball is in the shop today, and I failed psychic 101, so my mind reading abilities are not particularly hot. Could you share your table structure(s) and whatever code you have that's inserting/updating these tables?

Comment: Of course we need more info. Numeric ? Decimal, int.. ? what type ? What engine ? (I assume sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with EF. Whatever I just find what was wrong. In my model for Order I've forgot to add Range attribute.

```
[Range(0.00, 100000.00)]  
public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `Scale` value set to 0 ? If yes,set to 2 or more.

[image]

And If you are saving teh data using a stored procedure, make sure that the stored procedure parameter type is also same type.

Comment: Yes I have a scale numeric(19,4)

Comment: @Alternative : Check all the places you pass the value for it, Variables etc to make sure you use the same datatype to support your price with decimal point

Comment: I'm using the same datatype for all my "Price" or even "Total" variables. I solved the problem by adding [Range(xx, xx)] attribute like I said in my answer. I don't know if it's the best practice, but it work. What do you think ?

Comment: @Alternative: I do not see the word Entity Framework in your question!!! . Please provide more details when you write a question.

Comment: Yes sorry, but I didn't really know from what it could become. I'm begginer in asp, and I haven't a so large vision on it.